# How can I install a package from a different Ubuntu version via terminal?

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to install libeigen3-dev (3.3.2) from Yakkety while on Ubuntu 14.04. I don't want to simply download the deb file because I need to distribute this process to lots of other computers.

How can I do this?

Comment: First try the deb file. There is no guarantee it will install ;-) It is very unlikely.

Comment: It installs just fine. The package I'm talking about is just a [header file library](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen) . The newer version just handles [normalizing zero vectors](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=977#c8) differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/eigen3/libeigen3-dev_3.3~beta2-2ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libeigen3-dev_3.3~beta2-2ubuntu2_all.deb
```

As simple as that.

Comment: I should have specified via apt-get. I'm not familiar with deb files, and would like the location of the installed files to be as if it had been installed using apt-get. This would mean replacing the older eigen3 files.

Comment: This is the exact location where apt-get pulls the packages from. One of the official mirrors. And `dpkg` is what actually installs them using apt-get. Adding yakkety repos is a very bad idea.

Comment: Will it install things the same way?

Comment: Exactly the same way. `apt-get` is a wrapper for wget and dpkg.

Comment: You can use this link as well. http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/eigen3/libeigen3-doc_3.3~beta2-2ubuntu2_all.deb It is 100% official.

Comment: I see. I have found things to behave differently when installing via deb files versus install via PPA repositories in the past. Namely the location of the files installed.  If I use this method, can I still rely on the location of those header files being placed in `/usr/include/eigen3/`?

Comment: Location is set in the deb file. You maybe downloaded some non-Ubuntu debs.

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw your comment above. I didn't realize it was a wrapper. Ok. Sounds good. Thank you!